# If I'm posting a question about Oracle SQL query performance, what should I include in my question?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, database-design

If I am posting a question about a query against an Oracle database, what should I include in my question so that people have a chance to answer me?  How should I get this information?

Simply providing the poorly performing query may not be enough.

Comment: I have to ask the question: why is this a community wiki?

Comment: Because I really want this question to exist so we can point it when someone posts a "Why does this query go slow?" question without providing any useful information about the tables involves, indexes or waht they are trying to achieve.

Comment: A meta-question... Surely that's not programming related? :P

Comment: To my way of thinking this is not a community wiki post. It's specifically about tuning Oracle queries, which won't be of interest to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, get the full query plan using DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR using the sql_id and child_cursor_id from v$sql. Failing that (ie on older versions), try v$sql_plan and include filter and access predicates. EXPLAIN PLAN is fine if it actually shows the plan that was used.

DB version and edition (Express/Standard/Enterprise). Maybe the OS too.
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION

If you have any non-standard database parameters, it is useful to know (especially anything optimizer related).
select * from v$parameter where rownum < 5 and isdefault != 'TRUE';
*If you do a 
    alter session set events '10053 trace name context forever, level 1'
and parse a query, there'll be a log file that will include all the parameters used when optimizing a query *

Real world table sizes and column distributions (eg it is a million row table, with 30% of rows being "Red" etc). And the relevant stats off USER_TABLES, USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

How long it actually look, plus any SQL stats you have available (consistent gets, physical reads) from v$sql.

Also, who do you THINK it should be able to run faster. Do you think there's a better plan, or are you just crossing your fingers.

Answer (score 4):

- The schema definition of the tables involved.
- The indexes defined on those tables.
- The query you are executing.
- The resulting query execution plan

Comment: This also applies on SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

The query plan is always useful